# How could I improve my code for printing to a text file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, printf, dimension

I'm working with the open-source thermal simulator HotSpot 6.0, I seek to extract the dimensional parameters -x and -y onto a text file to use for a new thermal modeling tool.

I've tried terminal printing x and y locations:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Location in x: %u\n", i1);
fprintf(stdout, "Location in y: %u\n", j1);
```

The above code prints lines of i1 and j1 numbers, but I would like to have them saved to a text file.
The code below is my attempt at printing to a text file.

```
FILE *fptr;
fptr = fopen("Dimensions.txt","w");
fprintf(fptr,"%u\t %u\t",i1,j1);
fclose(fptr);
```

The output of the code above prints only one line of code. I would like to know why this is to fix it.

Comment: Remove the newline character and replace with spaces/tabs? You might also want to look at the width specifier for the format strings.

Comment: And perhaps a single `fprintf` with a format string having two specifiers?

Comment: That did make them separated by column, but it only creates one line of data compared to my fprintf(stdout) code

Comment: I don't understand your question. How many lines do you expect? And why?

Comment: Could you edit the question to add the desired output and what you're getting? Because it's getting kind of confusing.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Your edit have just invalidated the previous comments, but did not make it any clearer. You are printing one line and asking why it is printing one line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement suggestion:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned i1 = 101;
  unsigned j1 = 202;

  FILE *fptr = fopen("Dimensions.txt", "w");
  if (fptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can not open/create file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  fprintf(fptr, "%u %u\n", i1, j1);
  fclose(fptr);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What does it improve?

Comment: Er, why be cute with the comma operator in that error check and not a more usual `if (fptr == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "Can not open/create file\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. The question was different when I answered it (it used two `printf`). Now I'm a bit confused as to what the question asker wants.

Comment: @Shawn It was a bit hasty to my local formatter to not use so many lines. I'll adjust.